# Compare 2 timestamp values and do something with the result

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm pretty new to PHP. I started a website with products bidding for a project and i'm stuck on this thing..
I want to store the actual date and time when a new product is added to the page and another date and time (deadline) witch is 24 hours later.
I've done this in the adauga_admin.php page (the page that adds products details to mysql table)

adauga_admin.php :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$data=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$deadline=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+24 hours'));

// protejam impotriva injectiei de cod
$t = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['t']);
$s = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['s']);
$p = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['p']);
$d = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['d']);

$sql="INSERT INTO produse (titlu, stare, pret, descriere, data, deadline)
VALUES ('$t', '$s', '$p', '$d', '$data', '$deadline')";
$rez = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    if($rez) {
        header("location:produse_user.php");
    }

    else {
        echo "Probleme la adaugare";
    } 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the table with the products :

```
id | titlu | stare | pret |  descriere |        data         |      deadline       |
___________________________________________________________________________________
11 |  asd  |  asd  |  140 |    asd     | 2014-06-03 19:02:47 | 2014-06-04 19:02:47 |
```

And this is where I display the products to the users. From here they can bid for a product

produse_user.php :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
?>

<?php

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from produse");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>

<div class="produse"> 
<div class="produse-header"> 
<h4><?php echo $row['titlu'];?></h4>
<h5><?php echo $row['stare'];?></h5>
</div>
<div class="produse-continut">
<textarea readonly><?php echo $row['descriere'];?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="produse-pret"> 
<p><?php echo $row['pret'];?> lei</p>
</div>
<div class="produse-buton"> 
<a href="liciteaza.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Liciteaza</a>
</div></div>

<?php 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My goal is to make a script that displays on the poducts page for each product if is still available or expired.
I guess it is something like this but and don't know how to do it..

```
if ($data > $deadline) {
   echo "Expired";
}
else {
   echo "Available";
}
```

Comment: have you tried that? What's your actual question here?

Comment: I think you should store the date('Y-m-d H:i:s') to DB and compare that date time in your php script with current date time for checking 24 hours or else.

Comment: do you want to apply the logic in produse_user.php?

Comment: @fortune Yes, this is what i want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query or a variant on it.

```
select * from produse WHERE deadline >= NOW()
```

to exclude rows for which the deadline has already passed from your result set.

You can also do stuff like

```
select * from produse WHERE deadline >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
                        AND deadline < NOW()
```

to show products with deadlines between two hours ago and the present time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now my little project is complete :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
?>

<?php

$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$status = "";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from produse");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

if ($data > $row['deadline']) {

    $status = "Expired";
} else {

    $status = "Available";
}   

?>

<div class="produse"> 
<div class="produse-header"> 
<h4><?php echo $row['titlu'];?></h4>
<h5><?php echo $row['stare'];?></h5>
<h5><?php echo $status;?></h5>
</div>
<div class="produse-continut">
<textarea readonly><?php echo $row['descriere'];?></textarea>
</div>
<div class="produse-pret"> 
<p><?php echo $row['pret'];?> lei</p>
</div>
<div class="produse-buton"> 
<a href="liciteaza.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Liciteaza</a>
</div></div>

<?php 
} 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is working great but i chose to use Ollie's variant.

Comment: Yes Ollie's solution is the apt one. +1 vote for @Ollie Jones